# OneLogin: How to approve all pending users attached to specific role

Tags: onelogin

We have some users attached to different OneLogin roles via mapping rules. So, when a new user is created and satisfied by the mapping rule, then it is shown as the Pending state.(Here, we don't turn on the automatic approval for user provisioning)
What I'd like to do is to approve the user via API. I found the [OneLogin doc](https://developers.onelogin.com/api-docs/2/apps/list-users) which shows us to get the list of users assigned to the application. But it doesn't tell how to approve the users in the Pending state. Any ideas ? Thanks in advance.

Basically, I have checked these docs as well -> [List Users](https://developers.onelogin.com/api-docs/2/apps/list-users), [Get User Apps](https://developers.onelogin.com/api-docs/2/users/get-user-apps), [Update App](https://developers.onelogin.com/api-docs/2/apps/update-app)

Answer (score 0):

In the [Users API](https://developers.onelogin.com/api-docs/2/users/update-user), you have the PUT Update User request. You can use this to approve the pending states. After you get the user id for the request, you'd  just put this in the body:

```
{
    "state": 1
}
```

Let me know if you need any other help.